# file i/o problem

Tags: python, file-io

I am having trouble with a really simple problem. I'm trying to remove line breaks in a file and send the output to a new file. This is my code:

```
infile = open('seq.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
lines = infile.readlines()
for line in lines:
    par = line.strip('\n')

outfile = open('seqpar.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
for line in lines:
    outfile.write(par)
```

When I run the above code, the contents of the outfile (seqpar.txt) is completely blank. I've tried to search for I/O tutorials online, but I can't seem to locate any solutions to a similar problem. I'm really having trouble with understanding file I/O for some reason.Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Why do you have two `for` loops?  Why not read **and** write in a single loop?  Why write two?

Comment: Also, why store the stripped line in a variable that is never used again (`par`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other answers explain what's wrong with your code. Here's a more pythonic way of doing what you're trying to do:

```
with open('seq.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
    with open('seqpar.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(line.strip("\n"))
        # Or alternatively -- more efficient, but perhaps less pythonic:
        # outfile.write(infile.read().replace("\n", ""))
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually first tried to find a solution using the `with` statement as you outlined. I am learning this in the very excellent Diving into Python tutorial. I really appreciate you showing me the 'pythonic' method. I've saved this example for later use.

Answer (score 3):

```
par = line.strip('\n')
```

This isn't being stored anywhere, so every `line` read overwrites the previous `par`. Your final line in the input file is presumably blank, and that final line is all that gets written to the output file, so nothing gets written to the output - several times, once for each line in `lines`. You need to *append* each `line.strip('\n')` to `par`, rather than overwriting it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that your first `for` loop iterates over each line in the file, putting it in the variable `par`, each time overriding the same variable with the next line.

Once the loop as finished, `par` will contain the last line of the file, and the next for loop will write the last line of the file to the new file repeated `n` times, `n` being the number of lines in the first file.

Below is one way that would work:

```
infile = open('seq.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
lines = infile.readlines()

outfile = open('seqpar.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
for line in lines:
    outfile.write(line.stripe('\n')
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate you explaining the problem; now I understand.